# Use a custom java program to upload a compiled on command c program

Tags: java, c, arduino

I have a program in Java that operates based on commands that are hard coded into it. I want to have a command that will accept a string as a parameter and then take the string turn that string into a CPP file using the code below (which works flawlessly for me). There is a function in the cpp code below that accepts a string, called `printToLCD(boolean, String);` which when compiled and uploaded to my arduino uno will print a string and display it on my 16x2 lcd screen.

I want to use my Java program to be able to change the message on the LCD screen, however I want to use the function.

I have my program able to connect to the Arduino and read it's serial input however I can't compile the C code and upload it to the Arduino. Has anyone come across anyone doing something similar? Has anyone come across another project that is kinda similar?

Does anyone know how to compile C code and then upload the compiled result to the arduino?
I have taken a look at the Arduino IDE's methods for doing such a job and I can't find where they compile the code. Is that just brought on my clicking the button and then the result is stored in a string and then the string path is uploaded to the arduino?

The C code for the Arduino:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LCD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define I2C_ADDR    0x3F // <<----- Add your address here.  Find it from I2C Scanner
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN     3
#define En_pin  2
#define Rw_pin  1
#define Rs_pin  0
#define D4_pin  4
#define D5_pin  5
#define D6_pin  6
#define D7_pin  7
int n = 1;
LiquidCrystal_I2C   lcd(I2C_ADDR,En_pin,Rw_pin,Rs_pin,D4_pin,D5_pin,D6_pin,D7_pin);
void cls(){
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("                     "); 
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("                     "); 
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("                     "); 

}
void printToLCD(boolean setBacklight, char const textToPrint[]){
  lcd.home();
  lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN,POSITIVE);
  if(setBacklight){
    lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  } 
  else {
    lcd.setBacklight(LOW); 
  }
  int stringLength = strlen(textToPrint);
  if(stringLength <= 16 && stringLength > 0){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(textToPrint); 
  } 
  else if(stringLength >= 17 && stringLength <= 32){
    char *key2 = (char*)malloc(16);
    int o = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < (stringLength -16); j++){
      key2[j] = textToPrint[j+16]; 
      o = j;
    }
    for(int a = o; a < 17; a++){
      key2[a+1] = ' '; 
    }

    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(textToPrint);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(key2);
  } 
  else if(stringLength > 32){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Hey! You have to");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("many characters!");
  }
}
void setup()
{
  lcd.begin (16,2); //  <<----- My LCD was 16x2
  // Switch on the backlight
  lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN,POSITIVE);
  lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
  cls();
  printToLCD(true,"All hail our lord Google.");
}
void loop(){

}
```

Comment: This is probably documented in the Arduino IDE docs.  It must come with a compiler that you can invoke from the command line (probably a GNU cpp cross-compiler).  Once you figure that out it should be easy to invoke from Java.

Comment: I still have yet to find anything of the sort in the Arduino IDE docs.